# compilation problems using boost math

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, compilation

I used to installer from http://www.boostpro.com/download/ to build boost and would like to use some of the math functions. Something like this:

```
Plm[l][m] = boost::math::legendre_p(l,m,cosine);
```

Naturally, I included:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/spherical_harmonic.hpp>
```

And added the path to boost to my additional (boost\boost) include directories and the path to the lib (boost\lib) to the additional linker directories (VS2008). I'm getting some compilation errors I can't seem to figure out the cause:

> Error  6   error C2955: 'boost::mpl::if_' : use of class template requires template argument list  D:\work\multipoles\Project\boost\boost\math\policies\policy.hpp 724
>
> Error  2   error C2825: 'Policy': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'   D:\work\multipoles\Project\boost\boost\math\policies\policy.hpp 724
>
> Error  4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'promote_double_type' D:\work\multipoles\Project\boost\boost\math\policies\policy.hpp 724
>
> Error  5   error C2065: 'promote_double_type' : undeclared identifier  D:\work\multipoles\Project\boost\boost\math\policies\policy.hpp 724
>
> Error  3   error C2039: 'promote_double_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    D:\work\multipoles\Project\boost\boost\math\policies\policy.hpp 724

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: I know that these kind of problems can be caused by a missing ';' somewhere. However, I get the same compilation issues when I include boost on the first line of the file...

Comment: Can you show us the code you're compiling?

Comment: sure thing: This is the file I call the boost function from http://pastebin.com/iZQ9neBP. These are the included headers, just to be save: http://pastebin.com/e3Q2w1fA, http://pastebin.com/LqpU2eAp

Comment: Shouldn't you include boost libraries using angle brackets quotes instead of quotes ? (Or I missing something ?)

Comment: tried both (same compilation errors), but thx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this was though one. In my code, l and m are unsigned. But there is only an overload for legendre_p(int,int,T). Thus, my function call is mapped to legendre_p(int,T,&policy) (or so I think).